# Частица НЕ с прилагательным «характерный»

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

*Такое положение Витгенштейн считает **не** характерным для Вещи.*

Предложение из "Логико-философского трактата" философа Людвига Витгенштейна.

По какому правилу выбрана раздельная форма написания НЕ в данном случае?